# How to can i keep the count of event editing(number of time event edited/modified)

Tags: development, sharepoint-calendar

here I want to keep the maintain the count of event's editing means I want to keep track of specific event like how many time that event got updated/Modified?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you want to see how many times some item was edited?

If that is the case, there is a simple way to activate Versioning option in your list. You can find details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37).
After you enable Versioning, you can simply click on desired item and check how many versions of specific item are created. On link above you can find for SP versions 2007-2016 step by step.

Second option is if you want to see number of editing as a column, you can create column with default value of 1. After this, create simple SP designer workflow where that column will be increased each time item is edited.

Comment: Actualy I can see this property in camlquiery bulder,Only having issue with c#.
And I have tried the Above thing but my bad luck it is not working.

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013